# How to add an image in Storybook within a component

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, storybook

I am trying to add a logo image (svg) to my nav component. I am using Storybook and next.js.

I followed the config from [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#gatsby-focus-wrapper), but the image does not load in the storybook component.

Why is this?

```js
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  stories: [],
  addons: [],
  staticDirs: ['../public/images'],
};
```

```js
// Nav.stories.mdx
import {Nav} from './Nav'
import {Canvas, Meta, Story} from '@storybook/addon-docs'

<Meta title="micro/Nav" component={Nav} />

export const Template = (args) => <Nav {...args} />

# The Nav

Unauthenticated user

<Canvas>
  <Story name="nav-unauthenticated">{Template.bind({})}</Story>
</Canvas>
```

```js
//Nav.js
import logo from '../../public/images/logo.svg'

export const Nav = () => {
  return(
    <img {...logo} alt='logo'/>
  )
}
```

The logo does not appear in the nav
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've added it successfully, you need to do these:
1- add the static path as mentioned in the docs.
  `staticDirs: ['../public']`
2- rerun the storybook command after changing main.js
2- add the image file like `<img src="/images/img.png" />` to your component

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Simply add Images in public directory and add below code

```
<img src='/logo.png' />
```

Use within your component

Answer (score -1):

For serving example, Storybook-only images, ones that do not appear on your production environment I'd recommend going with simply importing images and referencing them using `src` prop, for example:

```
import imageFile from './static/image.png';

export const WithAnImage: Story = {
  render: () => <img src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />,
};
```

This way we avoid bloating `public` directory with Storybook-specific images.

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#import-assets-into-stories